# Drupal 7 - Delete old nodes with Node expire and their translated versions

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-rules

Problem with deleting nodes and their translations with [Node Expire](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_expire).

I've made a rule to delete the node when it's expire date is expired, but It only removes the node that has the expiry date and not the translated node. I have i18n_sync module that synchronize some of the data between the languages but I can't get it to synchronize the expiry date (not an option?). Anyone have some suggestions how to get it working or any other ideas? I'm not so familiar with Drupal but had to update a site for a client so I'm quite stuck.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the translated node have an expiration date at Publishing Options?

Comment: yes it does, but I would like to just enter the expiration date once and get all versions of the same "event" deleted after the date.

Answer (score 0):

At admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT_TYPE go to publishing options.
There you have **NODE EXPIRE
Default expiration date** ; Set that to: +30 day (example for expiring in 30 days after published). Then the rule you made to delete the nodes when it's expire date is expired should work fine.

Comment: Yea well I don't want to use a default, I want to give the node a specific date and that value should be copied to the other 2 nodes (3 languages on the site).